# How to release tombstone wire without cutting? And why won't it turn?

Tags: electrical, lighting, fluorescent

Small light with T8 bulb. Tombstone was almost impossible to twist to get the bulb out. Why?
Can the wires be removed from this style without cutting them? Tried poking small flat screwdriver around.
Saw another answer but completely different than mine.
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you getting an error that the picture is too large, or...?

Comment: When I have broken tombstone’s I use a spare piece of wire and slide it down next to the original until it just pushes the spring back but I can’t tell if you have enough room on these. Twisting while pulling is the only other way than popping them open, it’s broke so breaking it more won’t matter.

Answer (score 2):

Grab the wire quite firmly and twist and pull.  It *will* come out.

That type of tombstone, with the rotating guard, can be unnervingly stiff sometimes.  If you want to replace them with passive types, feel free - there are many styles of tombstone (how the base interacts with the fixture, but one type is dominant, and that looks like it.